# PLEASE HELP: Extracting Data from Buffer (Bluetooth & Handler problems with EditText)?

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, handler

I'm using Bluetooth Serial Data.

The information is "trapped" in the buffer and I can't show it on the Screen with my EditText...

```
04-16 13:58:28.483: I/debugging(2380): Receiving Data
04-16 13:58:28.484: I/debugging(2380): run success
04-16 13:58:28.487: I/debugging(2380): buffer read OK
```

HEX

```
04-16 13:58:28.489: I/debugging(2380): 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
```

ASCII:

```
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): ??0183600NEWDEVICE
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0147900:4239
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0147901:0200
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0147902:2971
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0157903:01598
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0157904:02754
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0157905:03383
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0157906:02590
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0187908:04.02.01
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0157909:19.45
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0117911:0
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): 0098540
04-16 13:58:28.492: I/debugging(2380): ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????? ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

After that the application crashes showing WEIRD messages (I put a extract):

```
04-03 22:23:37.503: I/ViewRootImpl(13520): No key event currently.
04-03 22:23:37.510: I/ViewRootImpl(13520): No motion event currently.
04-03 22:23:37.510: I/ViewRootImpl(13520): The current processed event of VRI is none
04-03 22:23:37.510: I/ViewRootImpl(13520): notify IMS Dump
04-03 22:23:37.545: D/ANRAppManager(13520): MSG HISTORY IN MAIN THREAD:
04-03 22:23:37.545: D/ANRAppManager(13520): Current kernel time : 28387613ms
04-03 22:23:37.545: D/ANRAppManager(13520): === LONGER MSG HISTORY IN MAIN THREAD ===
04-03 22:23:37.545: D/MessageQueue(13520): Dump first 20 messages in Queue:
```

I'm ussing the typical Handler:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.i(tag,"in handler");
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
        case SUCCESS_CONNECT:


            mTextView.setText("PACO",TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
          //DO SOMETHING
            ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conectar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String s = "conectado con Éxito";
            connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
            Log.i(tag,"connected");
            byte[] iniciar = new byte[]{(byte)0x05};
            // B01/n en Hexadecimal (Introducir para que Espirómetro envíe datos
            byte [] datos = new byte[] {(byte)0x42, (byte)0x30, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x0D};
            //byte [] datos = new byte[] {(byte)0x43, (byte)0x0D};
            connectedThread.write(iniciar);
            Log.i(tag, "waiting for commands");
            Log.i(tag, convertToHex(datos));
            //Get Data
            connectedThread.write (datos);
            Log.i(tag,"Receiving Data");
            connectedThread.run(); 
            //connectedThread.cancel();
            break;

        case MESSAGE_READ:
            Log.i(tag,"He estado aquí2");
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
            /*
            String string = new String(readBuf);
            Log.i(tag, string);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            */
            Log.i(tag,"He estado aquí");
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            mTextView.setText(readMessage);
            //added by AMJ in attempt to display variable in textview

            break;
        }

    }
};
```

And the typical ConnectedThread:

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {


        Log.i(tag, "run success");
        byte[] buffer;
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read() 

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs 
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream 
                buffer = new byte [256];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                Log.i(tag, "buffer read OK");
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity 
                Log.i(tag, convertToHex(buffer));             
                Log.i(tag, hexToAscii(convertToHex(buffer)));
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i(tag, "buffer read failed");
                System.out.print("read error"); 
                break;
            }
        }           

    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}

}
```

THANKS FOR HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

I would stop allocating the buffer every time I start reading.
What if your previous message gets garbage collected randomly?

So delete

```
buffer = new byte [256];
```

Then to still make it work during successive reads, replace

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
with
mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer.clone()).sendToTarget();
```

Can you send me your entire source code? I could take a look.

Comment: How can I? Do I send you my code in a private message? Or post here?

Comment: Email me @ rsavutiu@gmail.com. Also send instructions about your app, how to test, etc.

Comment: The problem is that for testing it you need the "Ashtma Monitor" Spirometer :(

Comment: Don't worry about that, we can find some other device to transmit data to. Actually, I would suggest you read BluetoothChat again, try to do EXACTLY what they do. However if you want, send me the code via Github or something, and I can debug it.